# Mongo group with geospatial condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have an issue when I try to aggregate results with a geospatial condition :

```
db.users.group({
    reduce: function(obj, prev) {
      prev.sums = {
        y_levels: prev.sums.y_levels + obj.current_y_level,
        x_levels: prev.sums.x_levels + obj.current_x_level,
        count: prev.sums.count + 1
      }
    },
    cond: {current_position: { $near: [56.553823, 8.565619, 10]}}, 
    initial: { sums: { y_levels: 0, x_levels: 0, count: 0 } }
});
```

produces :

```
uncaught exception: group command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: manual matcher config not allowed",
        "code" : 13285,
        "ok" : 0
```

I have no issue with a "regular" condition.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are seeing this bug here:
http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1742

The bug referenced uses the Map-Reduce command, but "group" is really just a prepared subset of Map-Reduce.

If you need this functionality, please vote it up so that it can be appropriately prioritized.