# MongoDB Count Inaccurate on Geospatial Queries

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, php-mongodb

I'm querying for documents that are close to a location (`$near` and `$maxDistance`) and fall within a date range (an `$or` with a 3 sets of `$gt`/`$lt` conditions relating to dates/schedules).

I find that `$cursor->count()` always returns 100 even if there are 100 or more results regardless of `limit()`.

It seems like `$cursor->skip()->limit()` work fine, allowing me to skip more than 100 results (when there are more than 100), but it bothers me that `count()` always returns 100 and there seems to be no way to determine the full count (other than paging until there are no more results).

I find references to [map reduce not working correctly with geospatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433322/mongo-group-with-geospatial-condition), and the mongodb docs reference a default `limit()` of 100.

> The above query finds the closest points to (50,50) and returns them sorted by distance (there is no need for an additional sort parameter). Use limit() to specify a maximum number of points to return (a default limit of 100 applies if unspecified):

Is this a known issue? I'm using the PHP driver.

Comment: What happens if you use '$within'? It seems more appropriate to count the amount of entries within a certain limit for this type of query than '$near'. Since $near would always expect you to pass the number of results you want back.

Comment: Well think about this:  How does mongo know how near you want it?  You have to specify a limit or use within because "near" really means "nearest".  If I told you give me all McDonalds near my house, you would probably say well what distance is near, or how many of the nearest ones do you want?  count() with no qualifier could technically return everything in your database if not given any qualifications because again what is "near".  Mongo says if you do not have qualifications then they call near the nearest 100.

Comment: @Tom I'll have to try $within. @Michael I'm using $maxDistance, but perhaps that isn't factored (updated question with that)?

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for add $or $and support to geo-spital for a year:

---

```
Estimate: Medium ( < 1 week)
Fix Version/s: planned but not scheduled
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3984

__
maybe they support this due 2014 ;)
__

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FD3xe6Jt

http://www.zopyx.de/blog/goodbye-mongodb

http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/20988881092/a-year-with-mongodb

http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/11/05/failing-with-mongodb/